# Error seen during upgrade from Hibernate3 to Hibernate5

Tags: upgrade, hibernate-5.x, hibernate3

I am upgrading from Hibernate3 to Hibernate5. As a first step in the process I replaced the hibernate3.jar with hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar.
Also, updated the code that resulted in compile issues because of the jars change.
However, when starting tomcat I see the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry)
```

The major.minor error is not resulting from different versions of compile vs runtime on my local code. Error seems to be originating from Hibernate.

Does anyone know of a possible cause for this?

Also, in the existing hbm.xml files the DOCTYPE used is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Did anyone come across this error during upgrade before?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because some classes in Hibernate - 5.2.1 needed Java 8 for functioning. I switched to Hibernate 5.1.0 and all worked well.